# Join Client to domain without setting dns

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, domain

I'm trying to join my clients to my domain.so i used [Netdom](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772217.aspx) command to join PCs.every thing is perfect but i have to set `DNS` for clients.i want to ask,there is any way to join PCs to domain without setting `DNS`?

Comment: Are you using DHCP in the network?

Comment: How are they getting their DNS configuration now and why doesn't it default to your domain controllers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to find a Domain Controller so that the clients can join the domain they need to query the DNS server that holds the DNS SRV records for the domain. The only way to do that is to set the clients to use the DNS servers that hold the AD DNS zones.

It might be possible to configure the clients current DNS servers to forward queries for the AD DNS zone to the appropriate DNS server for the AD zones, but that doesn't strike me as a viable option in your case.

Answer (score 3):

If you have DHCP enabled on the network, you can have the DHCP server hand out the DNS Server address via DHCP options.

From Technet (assuming a Windows Server DHCP server):

> Table 4.5 Default DHCP Options
>
> Code
>
> Option name
>
> Meaning
>
> 6 DNS servers Specifies a list of IP addresses for DNS name servers
>   available to the client

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958929.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to support a BYOD scenario where clients come to you with a preconfigured network profile with access to public DNS, and you don't mind a bit of information disclosure, you could simply create the DC Locator record in public DNS.

Let's say your AD Domain FQDN is `local.contoso.com`, go ahead and create the following records in public DNS:

```
dc01.local.contoso.com                  A             [Domain Controller IP] 
_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.local.contoso.com  SRV  0 0 389  dc01.local.contoso.com
```

Now clients will be able to locate your domain controller when you join them to the domain.

But even then, after joining, you still have to provide the clients with a preferred DNS server address that can resolve your AD zones.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the client registry settings, so it dont need local DNS configuration. Start Registry Editor (regedit.exe), go to:

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanManWorkstation\Parameters
```

- create a DWORD named `DNSNameResolutionRequired` with value `0`
- create a DWORD named `DomainCompatibilityMode` with value `1`